# Why I can't send an api request to database on heroku?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, knex.js

I have an app built with react, redux, node, and postgresql(knex), and I could deploy this app to heroku. However, all the api requests to database made in an app does not work. It is not fetching any data or I can not sign up.

In the app, I get a console error like this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 503(…)
...
```

Is there a way to fix this?
My knex configuration:

```
module.exports = {

  development: {
     client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      database: 'database5',
      user:     'user',
      password: ''
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  },

  staging: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      database: 'my_db',
      user:     'username',
      password: 'password'
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  },

  production: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  }

};
```

Error in heroku logs:

```
2016-10-25T13:06:04.647342+00:00 app[web.1]: Unhandled rejection Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
2016-10-25T13:06:04.647361+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:893:11)
2016-10-25T13:06:04.647362+00:00 app[web.1]:     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:916:20)
```

Comment: Can you show how are you calling the DB?

Comment: @FelipeSabino I just add it

Comment: Tou added how you configured the database, but not how you actually call it. Can you also share some code from tour request that is raising this error?

Comment: @FelipeSabino I just added an error in heroku logs when I try to sign up and save data in database.

Comment: Do you have `127.0.0.1:5432` for your `DATABASE_URL` environment values? If you don't know how to answer, execute `heroku config --app your_app_name_here`

Comment: @FelipeSabino I have a value like `postgres://fsgdsngindsingiew:l90buNIIV0WT8cvC-n9CvMvoT4@ec2-54-243-249-169.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dbj1eh5t2ks4t1`
Only 5432